# Cannot add viewcontroller´s frame to a scrollview in another viewcontroller

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, swipe

I want to add a swipe function to my app and swipe between viewcontrollers as in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jAlg5BnYUU
The source code for the tutorial is here: https://www.veasoftware.com/posts/swipe-navigation-in-swift-xcode-7-ios-9-tutorial

In that guide they are using `nib/xib` files that they create together with the corresponding viewcontrollers that they then use to call for in their ViewController´s constructors.

I have done exact the same and it is wokring as in the tutorial. But I also want use a ViewController that not has a `xib` file because it is on my storyboard. That viewcontroller is called `ViewController2` in my code below and it is the only that does not appear in the scrollview when I swipe. The other two do because I call for the `xibName` in the constructor call but ViewController2 does not have a `xib` file since it is on my storyboard.

So how can I add it to the scrollview so it appears when I swipe?

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let vc0 = ViewController0(nibName: "ViewController0", bundle: nil)

    self.addChildViewController(vc0)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc0.view)
    vc0.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let vc1 = ViewController1(nibName: "ViewController1", bundle: nil)

    var frame1 = vc1.view.frame
    frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
    vc1.view.frame = frame1

    self.addChildViewController(vc1)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc1.view)
    vc1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let vc2 = ViewController2()

    var frame2 = vc2.view.frame
    frame2.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
    vc2.view.frame = frame2

    self.addChildViewController(vc2)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc2.view)
    vc2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 3, self.view.frame.size.height - 66);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the following:

1) Getting the storyboard object programmatically.

2) Giving the View Controller 2 in your storyboard file a storyboard ID. You can do this by going to your Main.storyboard file and selecting the view controller you wish to give an identifier and then looking in the Identity Inspector (It should be in the under "Identity" section. [image]

3) Instantiating an instance of View Controller 2 with the storyboard method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. This method uses a storyboard ID as it's argument and adding that as the child of your scroll view.

Like so:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   //1
   let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

   //3
   let vc2 = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("<InsertStoryBoardID>") as! ViewController2
   self.addChildViewController(vc2)
   self.scrollView.addSubview(vc2.view)
   vc2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

   self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 3, self.view.frame.size.height - 66);
}
```

Hope this helps! Feel free to ask questions!

Comment: Thanks! That worked except that the frame size of the view of `ViewController2` was half as big as the other ViewController´s frame sizes (`ViewController0.view.frame` and `ViewController1.view.frame`). I solved that by setting `frame2.size.width = frame1.width`. Why is the frame size 50% of the other frame sizes as default?

Comment: @Rox, it may be because you have **Resize View From NIB**  checked in your Main.storyboard file for `ViewController2` (I believe this is the default). To check go to your Main.storyboard file, select the `ViewController2`, go to the attributes inspector, and under the "View Controller -> Layout" section unclick **Resize View From NIB** if it is checked. As shown in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520561/wrong-frame-value-while-accessing-the-view-from-storyboard-in-ios

Comment: Oh! That was the case! Thank you! :-)